# Looking for ideas on how to automate Flink deployment?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using aws EMR cluster setup for submitting Flink job. Today we log in EMR cluster and run following steps for submitting a job

1. Stop the job with savepoint.
2. Start new job with savepoint created in step 1

Now I wanted to associate this step with pipeline deployments. How can I do that? Is there any existing software/tools exists for automating Flink deployments?

We would also like to add features like auto-rollbacking deployment to previous version in case of exceptions/error

Comment: That doesn't help you with your EMR setup. But there is a [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/) available that allows a bit of lifecycle management of Flink jobs

Comment: hmm, Unfortunately I need to find some solution with EMR setup only. Wouldn't some script with Flink Rest API calls for job start/stop help ?